# Como buscar pelos ID's no banco e exibir os nomes na tela?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

No meu projeto JSF + Primefaces, tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "geracao")
public class Geracao {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente letras")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "Máximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Min(1)
    @Max(7)
    private Integer numero;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "total_pokemons", nullable = false)
    private Integer totalPokemons;

    public Geracao() {

    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "habilidade", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "nome" }))
public class Habilidade {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente letras")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "Máximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150, message = "Máximo de 150 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150, message = "Máximo de 150 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(name = "texto_in_game", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String textoInGame;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 150, name = "efeito_secundario", nullable = true)
    private String efeitoSecundario;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    private Geracao geracao;

    public Habilidade() {

    }

}
```

Tenho um relacionamento `ManyToOne` em *Habilidade* para cadastrar uma *Geração*. O campo *geracao*_id foi criado corretamente pelo Hibernate na tabela `Habilidade`. Estou tentando implementar na minha tela um `autoComplete` e eu li que o atributo `completMethod` é o responsável por chamar o método que vai carregar os objetos na tela. Como eu posso criar um método no meu controller de Habilidade que busque só pelos ID's de Geração mas carregue na tela os nomes das Gerações para eu selecionar uma ? Quero buscar por ID's pra ser uma consulta mais leve no banco.

Answer (score 1):

Prezado Douglas, primeiro verifique se realmente gerou no banco a chave estrangeira da tabela geracao, na tabela habilidade, para garantir o relacionamento. Se não gerou, utilize a anotation "@JoinColumn" antes da declaração da variável "private Geracao geracao".
  Quanto ao método, você poderia utilizar um método listar, estou anexando um que utilizo, num DAO Genérico, que serve para colocar os objetos de uma classe em uma lista, normalmente utilizo este método para preencher as comboBox. mas acho que nada impede que vc utilize no auto  completar. Segue o código.

```
public List<Entidade> listar() {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
    try {
        Criteria consulta = sessao.createCriteria(classe);
        List<Entidade> resultado = consulta.list();
        return resultado;
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        throw erro;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```

Método do bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void listar() {
    try {
        ClienteDAO clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();
        clientes = clienteDAO.listar();
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar listar os clientes");
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Método que cria a fábrica de sessões  `import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory fabricaDeSessoes = criarFabricaDeSessoes();

```
public static SessionFactory getFabricaDeSessoes() {
    return fabricaDeSessoes;
}

private static SessionFactory criarFabricaDeSessoes() {
    try {
        Configuration configuracao = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuracao.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro);

        return fabrica;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err
                .println("A fábrica de sessões não pode ser criada." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Obrigado, pra que serve o objeto sessao ?

Comment: A sessao, serve para abrir uma sessão do Hibernate para acessar os dados do banco e através do Criteria tbm do hibernate, faz a pesquisa no banco e armazena na variável resultado.

Comment: Como eu uso a injeção de dependência, vou precisar mesmo assim ?

Comment: No seu caso também ele busca por um id específico né? Quero que ele busque todos.

Comment: Quanto a injeção de dependência não sei te dizer.

Comment: Realmente, o método tá buscando por um id específico. Desculpe é que me equivoquei o método errado. vou editar e colocar o método correto. "listar".

Comment: Você pode postar o seu método getFabricaDeSessoes() ?